# Diferencia entre responseText y response en ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buenas!
Cual es la diferencia entre ResponseText y response del objeto XMLHttpRequest?
Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5):

De acuerdo a la [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/):

[`XMLHttpRequest#responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)

> The XMLHttpRequest.responseText property returns a DOMString that contains the response to the request as text, or null if the request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent.

[`XMLHttpRequest#response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response)

> The XMLHttpRequest.response property returns the response's body. It can be of the type ArrayBuffer, Blob, Document, JavaScript object, or a DOMString, depending of the value of XMLHttpRequest.responseType property.

#### ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

La propiedad `responseText` te devolverá **siempre** un DOMString, esto es básicamente un string normal (UTF 16), conteniendo la respuesta del servidor. Aún especifiques en la respuesta la cabecera `Content-Type`, al usar `responseText` obtendrás la representación en texto plano de la respuesta.

Por otro lado, la propiedad `response` obtiene la respuesta **de acuerdo al tipo que se espera** y que se ha especificado por medio de [`XMLHttpRequest#responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType). Es decir, si especificas que la respuesta será un JSON:

```
xhr.responseType = 'json';
```

Cuando accedas a la propiedad `response` obtendrás la respuesta ya parseada como un objeto literal. Lo mismo pasa si colocas un tipo de respuesta como arraybuffer para consumir una imagen por ejemplo; al usar la propiedad `response` vas a obtener el buffer correspondiente a la imagen.

Lo mismo aplica para [`XMLHttpRequest#responseXML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) que ya devuelve el XML como un [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).